# data adapter fill with spreadsheet not adding all columns

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datatable, oledbdataadapter

I'm trying to create a datatable based on spreadsheet contents by using the OleDbDataAdapter class.  I have 57 columns and nothing looks irregular in the 57th column, but the data from the 57th column will not add.  Columns 1-56 do add.  I have used this code numerous times with columns < 57 but when the user added the 57th column, it still only adds 56.  Here is the code:

```
using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "] WHERE (Select Count(*) from [" + sheetName + "])>0";
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        oda.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Print("Error in sheet name: {0}", e.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prior attempt to fiddle with inserting and deleting columns to reset the xlsx metadata in the schema was not successful. Assuming the excel file was somehow corrupt, I saved the sheet to csv, opened it in excel, saved it as excel, reran, and all 57 columns came in.